# Redirect removing (.htm) extension without using RewriteRule for a single page

Tags: .htaccess

I tried this simple .htaccess redirect to remove the (.htm) extension from a single page.

```
Redirect 301 /mypage.htm http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mypage
```

However it returned a 404 page not found?

Answer (score 1):

Dont use redirect, use mod-rewrite to rewrite your url.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)redirect "/mypage.htm" to "/mypage"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mypage\.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /mypage [NC,L,R]
#2)dont rewrite existing dirs and files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 #3)rewrite "/mypage" to "/mypage.php" 
 RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ /mypage.htm [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but why php mentioned in there
and so much code for one simple redirect?

Comment: Got it to work thanks! My htaccess file was in a subfolder so edited a bit.

Comment: Can this be slightly edited to redirect all .php pages in that folder?